# How can I fill the ring like this picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill a ring like this picture
[image]

With Geogebra, I tried it by plot `4<=x^2+y^2<=9`and this is the code in Geogebra

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-3.3,-3.3) rectangle (3.3,3.3);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black] (0.,0.) ellipse (2.cm and 2.cm);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black,fill=black,fill opacity=0.1] (0.,0.) ellipse (3.cm and 3.cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but, I got
[image]

How can I fill the ring as the firt picture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way to do this kind of operation is *fill* the center circle with `fill=white`, and to get the cross hatch fill pattern you use `pattern=crosshatch`:

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-3.3,-3.3) rectangle (3.3,3.3);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black] (0.,0.) ellipse (2.cm and 2.cm);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black,fill=black,fill opacity=0.1] (0.,0.) ellipse (3.cm and 3.cm);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black,fill=white] (0.,0.) ellipse (2.cm and 2.cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
% -------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-3.3,-3.3) rectangle (3.3,3.3);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black] (0.,0.) ellipse (2.cm and 2.cm);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black,fill=black,fill opacity=0.5, pattern=crosshatch] (0.,0.) ellipse (3.cm and 3.cm);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black,fill=white] (0.,0.) ellipse (2.cm and 2.cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And how about format of fill, none black?

Comment: @minthao_2011: Updated answer to include cross hatch pattern. Is this what the comment was about?

Comment: Two circles and `even odd rule` avoids the white fill.

Comment: Why 3 ellipses instead of 2 circles?

Answer (score 23):

Why all that typing?

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray!30,even odd rule]  (0,0) circle (3cm)
                                   (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
% -------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[even odd rule,pattern=crosshatch]  (0,0) circle (3cm)
                                         (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful brevity!

Comment: Why all that typing? `\tikz\draw[even odd rule, fill=gray!30] circle (3) circle (2);` ;)

Comment: @MarkWibrow: Yes, but too much brevity may some times be difficult to understand. (certainly not in this case though) :-)